# SpringBoot Rest api

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want to make a simple java application and I want to use CRUDREPOSITORY and my own repository. I have this:

```
@RestController
@Transactional
@ExposesResourceFor(Person.class)
@RequestMapping("/prueba")
public class PersonController  {

    @RequestMapping(value="/prueba", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String person(@RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="1") int id) {      
    return "hola"+id;
}

}
```

this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface IClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Long> {
}
```

The problem is that the CRUD works well, but I can´t call my localhost:8080/prueba/prueba because it gives a 404 error. I have try all and I cant access it, please help me!!

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: As Spring Boot App :)

Comment: When you start up your spring application it will list off the request mappings that it found from your controllers and any auto configured stuff (i.e. `@RepositoryRestResource`). Is there a mapping there for `/prueba/prueba`?

Comment: what happens for something like http://<server>/<app>/prueba/prueba?id=1

Comment: I think it was a problem about Spring-boot MVC dependency, suddenly it works when I added that dependency, I don´t know very well why this happened but if someone have the same problem, my solution was --> Add the MVC dependency and clean the project.   P.D: the mapping for /prueba/prueba does not appear in the list of the start, but now, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring Data REST serves up REST resources at the root URI, "/". There are multiple ways to change the base path.

With Spring Boot 1.2+, add below to application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

In your case: 
    spring.data.rest.basePath=/prueba/prueba
, assuming there is no override for server.contextPath in application.properties

Reference:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: The original question says that the CRUD works well (exposing the REST resource). The problem is the additional REST endpoint is not returning a value at `/prueba/prueba` which is defined in the annotations of the controller class and method.

Comment: The question did not say that whether CRUD works well on root path or the intended one.